# Correction: Calculating distribution function and determining density function of $Y =2X$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, density-function

Since we were not provided any solutions to our statistics exercises, I wanted to ask you guys for any corrections or errors I did on this exercise.

I will only upload a screenshot from my notes app. I hope that's ok.

The exercise was:
Let $X$ be a random variable with density $fX : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
fX(x) = (1
2
for x ∈ [2, 4]
0 else

a) Calculate the corresponding distribution function.

b) Determine the density of the random variable Y := 2X

Thank you :)

[image: Solutions]

Comment: "Density function is the derivative of distribution function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

point b is correct even there is a faster way to solve it. Just remembering that with a monotone transformation function there is a suitable formula that is

$$f_Y(y)=f_X\left(g^{-1}(y)\right) \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|$$

Thus being $x=\frac{y}{2}$ and $x'=\frac{1}{2}$ you immediately get

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[4;8]}(y)$$

as you found.

a) is wrong because when $x\geq 4$ the CDF $F_X(x)=1$

(remember also that, when calculating an integral function, i.e. $\int_2^x f(t)dt$ you cannot differentiate in $dx$ but you have to use another letter; you can use the letter you prefer but not $x$)

Comment: +1, Took the liberty of editing LaTeX to make it more clear

Comment: Thus the corrected CDF is

$$ F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  &x< 2 \\
\frac{x}{2}-1,  &2\leq x<4\\
1,  &x \geq4\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @gt6989b : well done! thanks